# UITableViewController inside of UINavigationController CRASH!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an app that implements a UINavigationController to load various UIViewControllers.

All works well, except when I attempt to load a UITableViewController.

The app crashes when I scroll with absolutely no details in the Console.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How about you provide details from the crash report on why it's crashing. My bet is it's something to do with your handling of the table view.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You need to provide some more details. Can you show some code please?

Comment: Moshe, in order to clearly show the issue I would have to paste a ton of code from several classes, so I started with a wide net at first hoping there was a known issue with implementing a UITableviewController inside of a UINavigationController.

Comment: removed tag 'xcode' http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info

Comment: Brian, placing a UITableViewController inside the stack of a UINavigationController is probably the most common view hierarchy across all iOS apps. Any app that offers the ability of "drilling down" into more specific data using a table view will be using a navigation controller. That said, I am sure someone will find an example where this is not true!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flying blind here, but this usually means your data source for the table is being released prematurely.

But as others have said, you need to update your question with a bit of code, crash log etc.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue. I thought the issue was with the TableViewController interacting with the NavigationViewController.